# Generate uniform random vectors

Tags: algorithms, trees, combinatorics, probability-theory, random-number-generator

**Problem :** Consider a random vector $v$ which is uniformly distributed over the sample space $S = \{v \in \mathbb{Z}^{n} : 1^Tv = a , v \ge 0\}$ . How to efficiently generate such random vector ?

note : I'm actually interested in $n=6,a=30$ .

**Attempt :** The size of the sample space [1] is the coefficient $c$ of $x^a$ in $(1+x+...+x^a)^n$ . So the probability of choosing any $v\in S$ is $1/c$ .

However for generation of such random vector , I could only think of first brute forcing with a tree to generate the whole sample space , then form a one-to-one correspondence with $[0,c]$ , so the problem  becomes generating uniform random variable in $[0,c]$ . I don't think this's efficient due to large brute forcing tree .

I wonder if there're any tricks to deal with this ?

[1] https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2947295/897319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the number of vectors $v \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $v \ge 0$ and $1^\top v = a$ is (by a stars-and-bars argument) exactly

$${a+n-1 \choose n -1}.$$

The number of such vectors with $v_1=b$ is exactly

$${a-b+n-2 \choose n-2}.$$

Therefore, the probability that $v_1=b$ is exactly

$${{a-b+n-2 \choose n-2} \over {a+n-1 \choose n-1}} .$$

It is possible to calculate the value of this for $b=0,1,\dots,a$.  So, calculate these values, then randomly choose $v_1$ according to this distribution.  Now you need to sample the value of $v'=(v_2,\dots,v_n)$ such that $v' \ge 0$ and $1^\top v' = a-b$.  This can be done through a recursive invocation of the same procedure (with $n$ replaced by $n-1$, and $a$ replaced with $a-b$).

This should give you an algorithm for sampling from this distribution, with running time proportional to $O(an)$ computations of bignum binomial coefficients.  For your values of $a,n$, this should be more than efficient enough.

**algorithm correctness :**

Since we require uniform distribution , the probability of any outcome should be $\frac{1}{\binom{a+n-1}{n-1}}$ .

In the algorithm the size of sample space at step $i+1$ is exactly the number of vectors with $v_k = b_k , \forall k < i +1$ , so by this sampling procedure , the probability of any outcome is
$$
\frac{\require{cancel}\bcancel{\binom{a-b_1+n-2}{n-2}}}{\binom{a+n-1}{n-1}} 
\cdot 
\frac{\require{cancel}\bcancel{\binom{a-b_1-b_2+n-3}{n-3}}}{\require{cancel}\bcancel{\binom{a-b_1+n-2}{n-2}}} 
... 
\frac{\require{cancel}\bcancel{ \binom{a-(\sum_{i=1,...,n-2}b_i) + 1 }{1} }}{\require{cancel}\bcancel{\binom{a-(\sum_{i=1,...,n-3}b_i)+2}{2}}}
\cdot 
\frac{\binom{a-\sum_{i=1,...,n-1}b_i}{0}}{\require{cancel}\bcancel{ \binom{a-(\sum_{i=1,...,n-2}b_i)+1}{1}}} 
= \frac{1}{\binom{a+n-1}{n-1}} 
$$

Comment: great answer , I think I understand the overall idea but there're few places that confuse me so I submitted an edit , please check

Comment: @Calvinfwc, oh, yes, thank you for catching all of those errors, and for fixing them for me!  Your understanding looks correct to me.  Thank you for being so gracious about my mistakes.